# How do I remove this newline before the <ul> starts?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.

I have a word followed by an `<ul>`. I made the unordered list have inline styling, but I want it to be on the same line as the word before it.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fm74R/4/

Use this template to make it look like: "Tags: funny unique Add a tag to the post"

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm74R/6/)

```
ul{
display:inline-block;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is give everything an inline form of display.

HTML:

```
Tags:
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li>funny</li>
    <li>unique</li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Add a tag to the post</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {margin:0; padding:0;display:inline;}
ul {margin:0; padding:0; display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fm74R/10/